# One word for heavily impacts?

Tags: clipping

Understanding social context 'heavily impacts' our connection to the characters.

Need to cut this sentence down and heavily impacts is a bit clunky!

Comment: Well, what do you mean to say? "Heavily impacts" is just a metaphor of 'affects greatly'.  Is that good or bad? Is it obvious already? What .. um .. social context do you intend to be saying this sentence in, and why do you need to cut it down? I'd wonder why you want to say it at all.

Answer (score 1):

***augment***

transitive verb

1: to make greater, more numerous, larger, or more intense

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

`Understanding social context influences our connection to the characters` ?

Not sure why you need to add `heavily`, `impacts` alone can convey the message.

Answer (score 0):

**SOME OPTIONS:**

[**enhances**](https://www.google.com/search?q=enhance%20synonym&oq=enhance%20synon&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j5.2925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of.

[**enriches**](https://www.google.com/search?q=enhance%20synonym&oq=enhance%20synon&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j5.2925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=enrich):

> improve or enhance the quality or value of.

[**strengthens**](https://www.google.com/search?q=enhance%20synonym&oq=enhance%20synon&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j5.2925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=strengthen):

> make or become stronger.

[**heightens**](https://www.google.com/search?q=enhance%20synonym&oq=enhance%20synon&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j5.2925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=heighten):

> make or become more intense.

---

***Sources:*** [Google Dictionary and by extension Oxford American College Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/)